# LiveRebel questions

Tags: jboss5.x, jrebel

I'm testing liverebel and I notices some strange behaviour :

My environment

1.) liverebel admin running on my local windows machine

2.) remote server linux CentOS with jboss5 server with liverebel agent

Questions:

1.) when I deploy the ear the name off the actual deployed ear on server changes to ROOT.ear...is that a normal behaviour?

2.) I have not fount any settings to change the behaviour in point 1...how could this be controlled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a LiveRebel product engineer, hope this helps.

This is expected behavior and there are no means to change it. Archive is renamed on deployment to root context path, because some app servers actually require it to have a special name.

However, I think it should only be done in the case of a WAR. This is something that we could look into.

Comment: hmm from my opininon this could be a configuration option, for exmaple jboss5 already has an exploaded ROOT.war deployd by default which is actualy the default welcome jboss server page....if my applicatoin is deployed like that it also gives me an error, I dont remmeber the error now but I will look into it to inform you further

Comment: another question is what if you have to deplyo two different ear application to the sam server...what happens in that case?

Comment: her is the error I get when I deploy my application with liverebel

 ERROR [org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.AbstractKernelController] (Thread-47) Error installing to PostClassLoader: name=vfszip:/usr/local/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/ROOT.ear/ state=ClassLoader mode=Manual requiredState=PostClassLoader
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Cannot process metadata

Comment: Thanks for the information, I've added it as an issue to be fixed.

Comment: is there a possibility to folow this issue...I woluld like to try again liverebel when this is fixed

Comment: Unfortunately no, it will be fixed in the next version.